# How to obtain the virtual text in a text property?

Tags: text-properties

I am writing tests for a small plugin which adds text properties with virtual text to a buffer.

I want to check what a text property's virtual text is on a given line.  Failing that, I would like to check the length of the virtual text.

The only way I can see to obtain the text property/ies on a line is `prop_list()`.  But the information it returns does not include the virtual text.  Not only that, it seems the `length` of the text property is always `1`.

Is there any way to get the text or its length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created this [pull request](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/12860) today to add support for getting the text associated with a text property.

Comment: That's the perfect answer, thank you!